# Scheduling/running mahout command in oozie

Tags: shell, hadoop, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I'm trying to run mahout command - sequence2sparse using oozie scheduler , but it is giving some error.
I tried running the mahout command using oozie - shell tags but nothing worked.

Following are the oozie workflow -

```
 <action name="mahoutSeq2Sparse">
      <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <configuration>
            <property>
              <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
              <value>${queueName}</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
        <exec>mahout seq2sparse</exec>
         <argument>-i</argument>
         <argument>${nameNode}/tmp/Clustering/seqOutput</argument>
         <argument>-o</argument>
         <argument>${nameNode}/tmp/Clustering/seqToSparse</argument>
         <argument>-ow</argument>
         <argument>-nv</argument>
         <argument>-x</argument>
         <argument>100</argument>
         <argument>-n</argument>
         <argument>2</argument>
         <argument>-wt</argument>
         <argument>tf</argument>
         <capture-output/>
     </shell>
 <ok to="brandCanopyInitialCluster" />
    <error to="fail" />
</action>
```

I also tried by creating a shell script and run it in oozie

```
 <action name="mahoutSeq2Sparse">
       <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <configuration>
            <property>
              <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
              <value>${queueName}</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
        <exec>${EXEC}</exec>
        <file>${EXEC}#${EXEC}</file>
     </shell>

    <ok to="brandCanopyInitialCluster" />
    <error to="fail" />
</action>
```

with job.properties as

```
nameNode=hdfs://abc02:8020
jobTracker=http://abc02:8050/
 clusteringJobInput=hdfs://abc02:8020/tmp/Activity/000000_0
queueName=default
oozie.wf.application.path=hdfs://abc02:8020/tmp/workflow/
oozie.use.system.libpath=true
EXEC=generatingBrandSparseFile.sh
```

and generatingBrandSparseFile.sh is

```
    export INPUT_PATH="hdfs://abc02:8020/tmp/Clustering/seqOutput"
export OUTPUT_PATH="hdfs://abc02:8020/tmp/Clustering/seqToSparse"


sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chmod -R 777     "hdfs://abc02:8020/tmp/Clustering/seqOutput"

mahout seq2sparse -i ${INPUT_PATH} -o ${OUTPUT_PATH} -ow -nv -x 100  -n 2 -wt tf
sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chmod -R 777 ${OUTPUT_PATH}
```

but none of the option is working.
The error with the later one is -

> SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
>   SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
>   sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
>   15/06/05 12:23:59 WARN driver.MahoutDriver: No seq2sparse.props found on classpath, will use command-line arguments only
>   15/06/05 12:24:01 INFO vectorizer.SparseVectorsFromSequenceFiles: Maximum n-gram size is: 1

For `sudo: no tty present` this error I have commented out 
/etc/sudoers - 
Defaults    !requiretty

Mahout is installed on the node where oozie server is installed.

Also the following oozie workflow is not valid-

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4" name="map-reduce-wf">
<action name="mahoutSeq2Sparse">
       <ssh>
        <host>rootUserName@abc05.ad.abc.com<host>
        <command>mahout seq2sparse</command>
        <args>-i</arg>
        <args>${nameNode}/tmp/Clustering/seqOutput</arg>
        <args>-o</arg>
        <args>${nameNode}/tmp/Clustering/seqToSparse</arg>
        <args>-ow</args>
        <args>-nv</args>
        <args>-x</args>
        <args>100</args>
        <args>-n</args>
        <args>2</args>
        <args>-wt</args>
        <args>tf</args>
         <capture-output/>
      </ssh>

    <ok to="brandCanopyInitialCluster" />
    <error to="fail" />
</action>
```

Error- `Error: E0701 : E0701: XML schema error, cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'ssh'. One of '{"uri:oozie:workflow:0.4":map-reduce, "uri:oozie:workflow:0.4":pig, "uri:oozie:workflow:0.4":sub-workflow, "uri:oozie:workflow:0.4":fs, "uri:oozie:workflow:0.4":java, WC[##other:"uri:oozie:workflow:0.4"]}' is expected.`

Will installing mahout on all the nodes will help?- (oozie can run the script on any node).
Is there a way to make mahout available on hadoop cluster?

Any other solution is also welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: 
I have changed the approach slightly, and now I am calling the seq2sparse class directly. The workflow is -

```
 <action name="mahoutSeq2Sparse">
    <java>
      <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
      <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>

       <configuration>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                <value>${queueName}</value>
            </property>

        </configuration>
            <main-class>org.apache.mahout.vectorizer.SparseVectorsFromSequenceFiles</main-class>
            <arg>-i</arg>
         <arg>${nameNode}/tmp/OozieData/Clustering/seqOutput</arg>
         <arg>-o</arg>
         <arg>${nameNode}/tmp/OozieData/Clustering/seqToSparse</arg>
         <arg>-ow</arg>
         <arg>-nv</arg>
         <arg>-x</arg>
         <arg>100</arg>
         <arg>-n</arg>
         <arg>2</arg>
         <arg>-wt</arg>
         <arg>tf</arg>

    </java>
    <ok to="CanopyInitialCluster"/>
    <error to="fail"/>
</action>
```

Still the job is not running , the error is

```
    >>> Invoking Main class now >>>

Main class        : org.apache.mahout.vectorizer.SparseVectorsFromSequenceFiles
Arguments         :
                    -i
                    hdfs://abc:8020/tmp/OozieData/Clustering/seqOutput
                    -o
                    hdfs://abc:8020/tmp/OozieData/Clustering/seqToSparse
                    -ow
                    -nv
                    -x
                    100
                    -n
                    2
                    -wt
                    tf

Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat

<<< Invocation of Main class completed <<<

Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain], main() threw exception, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Job failed!
org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMainException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Job failed!
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain.run(JavaMain.java:58)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:39)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain.main(JavaMain.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:450)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Job failed!
    at org.apache.mahout.vectorizer.DictionaryVectorizer.startWordCounting(DictionaryVectorizer.java:368)
    at org.apache.mahout.vectorizer.DictionaryVectorizer.createTermFrequencyVectors(DictionaryVectorizer.java:179)
    at org.apache.mahout.vectorizer.SparseVectorsFromSequenceFiles.run(SparseVectorsFromSequenceFiles.java:288)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at org.apache.mahout.vectorizer.SparseVectorsFromSequenceFiles.main(SparseVectorsFromSequenceFiles.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain.run(JavaMain.java:55)
    ... 15 more

Oozie Launcher failed, finishing Hadoop job gracefully

Oozie Launcher, uploading action data to HDFS sequence file: hdfs://vchniecnveg02:8020/user/root/oozie-oozi/0000054-150604142118313-oozie-oozi-W/mahoutSeq2Sparse--java/action-data.seq

Oozie Launcher ends
```

Answer (score 0):

Those errors on Oozie are very frustrating. From my experience, most of them are produced by a typo in the xml or in the parameter order.

On your last workflow, you didn't close the host tag:

```
<host>rootUserName@abc05.ad.abc.com<host>
```

should be

```
<host>rootUserName@abc05.ad.abc.com</host>
```

For the shell error, first I recommend to use the version 0.2 (defined here : https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.0.0/DG_ShellActionExtension.html#AE.A_Appendix_A_Shell_XML-Schema) and to remove all the parameters and everything not useful to start the action (do not care about the results).

You need to use :

```
<shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.2">
```

Comment: I used version 0.2 with the workflow as -
    <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
   <configuration>
                <property>
                  <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                  <value>${queueName}</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
            <exec>mahout seq2sparse</exec>
         <capture-output/>
         </shell>
Ozzie throwing error

Comment: Error -
`Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.ShellMain], main() threw exception, Cannot run program "mahout seq2sparse" (in directory "/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/root/appcache/application_1433401307677_0077/container_1433401307677_0077_01_000002"): error=2, No such file or directory
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mahout seq2sparse" (in directory "/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/root/appcache/application_1433401307677_0077/container_1433401307677_0077_01_000002"): error=2, No such file or directory
 `

Comment: You need to specify the full path of mahout.

Comment: I specified the full path of local file directory of the node where I am submitting the job. No use. Same error.

Comment: I specified the full path of local file directory of the node where I am submitting the job. No use. Same error.
Now to make mahout available on all nodes, it has to be on HDFS or shared lib.
Now how to make mahout availale in HDFS or what all has to be pasted in lib folder?

Comment: You could `put` it on hdfs or ship it with distriibutedcache

Comment: Hi, I tried with a different approach, still facing some issue.
Thanks in advance.